# Twig_Error_Loader: Template is not defined - Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I created an `include` in Drupal:

`{% include directory ~ '/partials/header.html.twig' %}`

but I am getting this error:

`Twig_Error_Loader: Template "themes/custom/mytheme/partials/header.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "themes/custom/mytheme/partials/header.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.) in "themes/custom/mytheme/page--front.html.twig" at line 1. in Twig_Loader_Chain->getCacheKey() (line 115 of vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php).`

According to Drupal and Twig documentation, I am doing it the right way.

I have a directory called `partials` and a file called `header.html.twig`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am running Drupal in MAMP and OSX, El Capitan. Drupal 8.3.7

Comment: Hi did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yes, many times!

Comment: Can you add on the topic the version of drupal plz. And did you attach your theme to the registry, is a new module or did you overwriting core files?

Comment: It is Drupal 8.3.7 I have not attached my theme to the registry, not a new module and I have not touched the core files.

Comment: So you got 2 solution create a new module make a hook to attach regitry to your template or overwriting the you using template but this mean you can't update the template or work on overwriting the core the first solution is the best, regards. Solution of your problem here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25846/how-to-tell-drupal-to-look-for-templates-in-module-directory

Comment: Overwriting core, mean you have to take care of drupal updates because if the template add some update in queue, it mean you lost all the change you did on this template.

Comment: Try to add `/` before `directory`: `{% include '/' ~ directory ~ ... %}`. Though, your initial code should work...

Answer (score 8):

When using the `include` or `extends` of Twig with Drupal 8, you have to specify the theme/modules namespace.

Here the complete explanation from Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/node/2143557

Plus, you should add your **partials files** into the **templates** folder of your custom theme. It's a best practice.

---

**Usage example**

```
{% include "@mytheme/partials/favicons.html.twig" %}
```

Comment: Thanks! I moved it into the templates folder and it works fine now! Noob mistake, still learning :)

Comment: Happy it helps you ! There is no noob mistake, we always learn new thingy ^^.
Happy codding to you.